# Include a comma after item if it exists

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I have a section that displays contact information on a site, like so:

```
<?php  echo "" . $address1. ", " . $address2. ", " . $city. ", " . $state. ", " . $zip_code . "";  ?>
```

However, the comma that follows `$address2` shows up whether that content exists or not. Using this code, how can I make the comma show up conditionally, only if `$address2` exists?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, you could do `$address1 . (!empty($address2) ? ", $address2" : '') .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implode is useful as glue.  Here we place the address in an array and filter (to remove empties).  Then join with the commas:

```
<?php

$address1 = 'Flat 203';
$address2 = '56B Whitehaven Mansions';
$state    = 'London';
$zip_code = '';

echo implode(', ', array_filter([$address1, $address2, $state, $zip_code]));
```

Output:

```
Flat 203, 56B Whitehaven Mansions, London
```

Comment: this is simple and efficient way

Answer (score 0):

try this i think it will work

```
<?php 
if(!isset($address1)){$address1=$address1.",";}
if(!isset($address2)){$address2=$address2.",";}
if(!isset($city)){$city=$city.",";}
if(!isset($zip_code)){$zip_code=$zip_code.",";}

echo $address1.$address2.$city.$state.$zip_code;  

?>
```